# GL Triangle in Unity displayed incorrectly in VR Headset

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to test out how it would be to render an assortment of 2D Shapes in in the screen on an existing unity VR Application.

I started by adding this code onPostRender:

```
  GL.PushMatrix();
  GL.LoadOrtho();
  GL.Begin(GL.TRIANGLES);
  GL.Color(Color.red); // This doesn't work. 
  GL.Vertex3(0.25f, 0.25f, -50);
  GL.Vertex3(0.5f, 0.75f, -50);
  GL.Vertex3(0.75f, 0.25f, -50);
  GL.End();
  GL.PopMatrix();
```

By following some examples and documentation. This does draw a triangle in white (the last thing drawn is a white cube that is moving from side to side on the screen) and more or less where I wanted however when I look into the headset I see the triangle as double.

I supposed that this is because some transformation needs to be applied for the right enad left eye rendering, but I have not idea how to do  this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it. IN case this helps anyone. Here is the working code:

```
void OnRenderObject(){


    float Z = 1;

    lineMaterial.SetPass(0);
    GL.PushMatrix();
    
    var proj = Matrix4x4.Ortho(0, 1, 0, 1, -1, 100);

    GL.LoadIdentity();      
    GL.MultMatrix(transform.localToWorldMatrix);      
    GL.MultMatrix(Camera.main.projectionMatrix);
    GL.MultMatrix(proj);      

    GL.Begin(GL.TRIANGLES);
    GL.Vertex3(0.25f, 0.25f, Z);
    GL.Vertex3(0.5f, 0.75f, Z);
    GL.Vertex3(0.75f, 0.25f, Z);
    GL.End();
    GL.PopMatrix();                 

}
```

So the key was to break up the Ortho Loading into two parts which I was able to do thanks to the documentation. I loaded the identity matrix (to start from scratch so to speak) and applied both the local to world transformation matrix and the main.projectionMatrix. lineMaterial was simply created to provide a solid color for the triangle.

And was created just like it is with the same name and everything in the doc here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GL.html